# I'm unable to assign values to array index. I have to assign values to individual variables

Tags: java, arrays

I have two classes, The variable (name1_i) in class Child (name of my second class) prints null value yet I'm expecting it to print "Tom" as assigned.

```
class parent{
    String name1="Tom",name2="John",name3="Harry";
    child pere = new child();
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        child.introduce();
    }
}
class child{
    public static String name1_i,name2_i,name3_i;
    public static void introduce(){
        parent variable = new parent();
        String[] names_i = {name1_i,name2_i,name3_i};
        String[] names = {variable.name1 , variable.name2 , variable.name3 };
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        //names_i[0] = name1_i = names[0];
        names_i[0] = names[0];
        //name1_i = names_i[0];
        System.out.println(names_i[0]);
        System.out.println(name1_i + "  <-- Expecting Tom");
    }
}
```

When I directly assign values to variables i.e `name1_i = "Tom";` (comment line 18) - it returns the expected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic works fine. The problem is that you have many syntax error in your code. Try to use the following and it will work:

```
public class Parent {

   public String name1="Tom",name2="John",name3="Harry";
    
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        Child pere = new Child();
        pere.introduce();
    }
    
}

class Child{
    public static String name1_i,name2_i,name3_i;
    public static void introduce(){
        Parent variable = new Parent();
        String[] names_i = {name1_i,name2_i,name3_i};
        String[] names = {variable.name1 , variable.name2 , variable.name3 };
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        //names_i[0] = name1_i = names[0];
        names_i[0] = names[0];
        //name1_i = names_i[0];
        System.out.println(names_i[0]);
        System.out.println(name1_i + "  <-- Expecting Tom");
    }
}
```

Once you become more familiar with Java (syntax, packaging and other basic aspect of the language) then try to get a good book on Object Oriented (OO) programming. At the moment your code doesn't comply with the OO standards.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I've run the code and it still gives me the same result

Comment: Maybe it's your setup. When I run the code, it printed "Tom". The only thing I left out in the example, I posted is the packaging. I created a test package and put the Parent and the Child in the test package.

Comment: Its printing Tom for variable (names_i[0]) and Null for variable (name1_i).

Comment: ROY: Printing null for name1_i is an expected behavior, because you have no assignment for this variable. The only assignment in the Child.introduce() is done to names_i[0].  Why do you expect the name1_i to display "Tom"? did you assigned any value to name1_i somewhere in the code that I am not privy of?

Comment: i would like to bring to your attention that (names_i[0]) is an array index containing name1_i : -->String[] names_i = {name1_i,name2_i,name3_i};.Which should print the same value.

Comment: In your code name1_i, name2_i and name3_i are basically sitting there with null values. You had not made any assignments to these variables. If you use a debugger and step through your code you will see what is going on in the code. The only assignment you have made is names_i[0] to names[0] and took name1_i out of the picture. What you need to do is name1_i=name[0], name2_i=name[0], name3_i=names[0] and then you will see name1_i, name2_i and name3_i all  print "Tom". Hope this clarifies your understandings of variable assignment and arrays

Comment: I've understood. Much appreciated. How would i go about it if I want to assign values to name1_i,name2_i.name3_i using loop? I want to populate the values of names[] into variables in names1_i[] using loop.i.e                                                                           
    for(int j=0;j<names.length;j++){
        names_i[j] = names[j];
 
        System.out.println(names_i[j]);
}

Comment: Typically, one uses a loop to initialize an array or a collection but not stand-alone variables like names1_i, names2_i, and so on. It's easier to make a direct value assignment to such variables i.e. names1_i="Joe", names2_i="John". Looking at your code, I do not discern the purpose behind names1_i, names2_i, and names3_i variables. Furthermore, I am not sure why they are declared as static variables? Static variables typically declared at the class level with global visibilities, while non-static variables are either object data members or local variables within the method.

Comment: Now I understand .Thank you very much, you've been of great help.

Comment: Well, I am glad everything is clear. If you are happy would you please check my answer (which was answer #2) as accepted? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning empty string variables to the array names_i then you are replacing the index 0 at array names_i with the value at index 0 of the array names.

If you need to keep your current implementation, you need to assign values to static String variables in the class child before adding them to the array and don't replace the values at array names_i with values from names array.

Comment: could you kindly post a snippet of the code